# Laravel 4 - Can't add to message bag?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

This is probably because I did something wrong and changed something but the error appeared suddendly everywhere I was adding error messages for validation. Here is an example:

```
$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules, $messages);
$messages = $validator->errors();
$operation = Operation::find(Input::get('operation_id'));
if($operation->membersNeeded()<Input::get('max')){
    $error=1;
    $messages->add('limit', 'You can only have '.$operation->membersNeeded().' more hostesses on this operation');
}
```

Gives me the following error:

```
 Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException

 Call to a member function add() on a non-object
```

And the line selected would be where y use add() to add my error message. This was working fine and I was editing other parts of the website and now suddendly it doesn't work. It puzzles me.

Comment: This probably won't be it- but you're re-using the `$messages` variable for validation messages and the returned message bag object. It could be an idea to rename one of those so its clearer what you're using.

Comment: I tried that to no avail :( if I dd($messages) before I try to add the message I get array(1) { ["unique_with"]=> string(44) "uniquewith-validator::validation.unique_with" }

Comment: What do you get if you `dd($messages)` when the validation (as in, validation from the validator) fails? I'm wondering if you don't end up with a `MessageBag` if the validation succeeds, in which case the solution would be to check that `$messages` is a `MessageBag` (and if it isn't, making it one) before attempting to `add()` to it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably safer to instantiate your own MessageBag and merge them with validator to ensure it doesn't return you NULL when validation passes.

Note that I'm renaming your `$messages` to `$errorMessages` since you're using the same variable name for custom validation message and error messages.

```
$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules, $messages);

// New MessageBag
$errorMessages = new Illuminate\Support\MessageBag;

// Check if there is actually any errors
if ($validator->fails()) {
    $errorMessages->merge($validator->errors()->toArray());
}

// The rest of your custom validation
$operation = Operation::find(Input::get('operation_id'));
if($operation->membersNeeded()<Input::get('max')){
    $error=1;
    $errorMessages->add('limit', 'You can only have '.$operation->membersNeeded().' more hostesses on this operation');
}
```